# Variable doesn't have a value assigned from the recordset PHP

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I am a total newbie to PHP and this is in fact my first construction in the language.

I am trying to integrate PayPal into a website using the **IPN facility**. This part works quite well however when I try to verify the second `POST` from PayPal after completion of the payment querying the database brings back the desired results but the `customerID` variable I have assigned the result to is not populating and therefore the second query is not completing and failing at that point. I've narrowed it down to the part shown below and I can only think that there is something wrong in the while loop getting the values from the recordset. The other variables in the first query are assigned from the POST back from PayPal

The code is as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT customer.cust_id FROM customer INNER JOIN transaction ON transaction.cust_id = customer.cust_id WHERE last_name = '".$surname."' AND email = '".$payer_email."' AND paypal_txn_id = '".$txnID."'";

$results = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

if($results){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_NUM)){

            $custID = $row[0];                                                  

            $_SESSION['customerID'] = $custID;
    }
    mysqli_free_result($results);                               
}
else{
    //send an email to say that something went wrong    

    //end this code execution
    exit();
}

$customerID = $_SESSION['customerID'];

$q = "SELECT * FROM transaction INNER JOIN customer ON customer.cust_id = transaction.cust_id WHERE customer.cust_id = ".$customerID." AND paypal_txn_id = '".$txnID."'";

$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

if($r){
    $array = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $stored_amount = $array['amount'];
    $stored_paymentStatus = $array['payment_status'];
    $stored_paypal_txn_id = $array['paypal_txn_id'];
    $transaction_id = $array['trans_id'];   

    mysqli_free_result($r);                             
}
else{
    //send an email to say that something went wrong    

    //end this code execution
    exit();
}
```

I thought that this may be due to variable scope however after reading around I find that the scope of variables is not an issue when inside if statements. I assigned the customer ID to a session variable but this is also blank if I use `print_r($_SESSION)`. I've tried `MYSQLI_NUM` and `MYSQLI_ASSOC` and got the same result. I can only assume that this is a daft error that I can't see as I'm quite green when it comes to PHP and have been staring at this for some time now!

Many thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: did you (even) start the session? `session_start();` <<< that.

Comment: Yes I used that at the top of the page. All other variables in the session data get printed out when I use the print_r except this one. That's why I thought it wasn't being assigned in the first place at the while loop.

Comment: `$_SESSION['customerID'] = $custID;` and `$customerID = $_SESSION['customerID'];` - You seem to be reassigning the session array here. Use `var_dump();` splashed around your code and you'll see where it starts to break. Check for errors also http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: I also don't see where `$txnID` is assigned and other variables. Again, check for errors as outlined above.

Comment: Oops left that second customerID in from when I thought it might be a scope thing. Thanks I'll give that a go then. $txnID is assigned from the POST response from PayPal. I left that bit off as it seems to work nicely.